# subtracting one query from the other one

Tags: ms-access

Can anyone tell me how to subtract a query from another query

```
strNewSql4 = "SELECT tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber, tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel    FROM tblRevRelLog_Detail"
  strNewSql4 = strNewSql4 & " WHERE tblRevRelLog_Detail.RevRelTrackingNumber = """ & tempTrackingNumber & """;"

   strNewSql3 = "SELECT tblEventLog.PartNumber FROM tblEventLog WHERE tblEventLog.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper'AND tblEventLog.TrackingNumber = """ & tempTrackingNumber & """"
```

I want the result for strNewSql4 - strNewSql3 as strNewSql1

Answer (score 1):

You can create sub queries and LEFT JOIN them on a suitable field, selecting the values that have a Null value for the selected field.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to express this query, such as a join, or using "NOT IN" with a sub-query, however the best choice based on the information given in your question is probably to use "NOT EXISTS", as follows:

```
SELECT tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber, tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel
FROM tblRevRelLog_Detail
WHERE tblRevRelLog_Detail.RevRelTrackingNumber = """ & tempTrackingNumber & """
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblEventLog
                 WHERE tblEventLog.PartNumber = tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber
                   AND tblEventLog.TrackingNumber =
                       tblRevRelLog_Detail.RevRelTrackingNumber
                   AND tblEventLog.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper')
```

Comment: Jet/ACE does not optimize NOT IN and NOT EXISTS well -- you may find that it doesn't use the indexes on both sides of the comparison. A LEFT JOIN, on the other hand, will always use both indexes.